# Did a merge occur from a specific branch into master?

Tags: git, version-control, git-rev-list

I have two primary branches within a Git repository - develop and master. New feature development occurs in branches off of develop, which are then merged into master for deployment.

I would like to determine if a merge has occurred from develop into master since a certain time. I'm not even really interested in the actual commits themselves, only that *something* from develop has been merged into master.

I have tried:

`git rev-list --merges origin/develop..origin/master --since <date> | wc -l`

for a period where I know there are merges, but it always seems to return a zero.

**Update**

Also, I have tried to build it up, step-by-step. Starting with:

`git rev-list --merges origin/master --since <date>`

I get all of the merges into master, both from the develop branch and any hotfix branches that may exist. It's only when I add the 'origin/develop' constraint that I get nothing in the results.

Comment: Have you tried building the command step by step, to see if you get anything? For what's worth, your command seems to work for me.

Comment: See above for update. Is the issue with how I am referring to the branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the last time a branch was merged in, I would use `git merge-base`. This shows the latest commit that both the branches have in common.

```
git merge-base origin/develop origin/master
```

This will provide the latest common SHA in both branches giving you an idea when they were last merged. You can pipe the commit SHA into `git log` and see the last commit.

```
git merge-base origin/develop origin/master | xargs git log -1
```

If you want to see all the commits on the branch since this SHA:

```
git merge-base origin/develop origin/master | xargs -I sha git log sha..origin/develop
```

With this you will be able to see a list of all the commits made on `origin/develop` that are not yet on `origin/master`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems to be on the right track, except merge-base is also including changes in master (such as a hotfix) that have been merged down into develop. Is there a way to only get merges from develop into master?

Answer (score 0):

Another option should be:

```
git log --merges --since=<date> --oneline origin/develop..origin/master
```

- --merges tells log to only show merges
- --oneline is optional and formats the output